# Db delete query always returns true

Tags: postgresql, go

I am using golang with postgres. I want to delete users from my table by passing in the Id for that user. When I run the code below I always get true. Even when I pass in a ID that does not exist in the table. Is that normal? Does DB.Exec return err if the user ID is not in the database?

```
func DeleteUser(ID int){
    err = nil
    _, err := DB.Exec("DELETE FROM Users WHERE user_id=$1", ID)

    if err == nil {

        return true
    }

    return false

}
```

Comment: It's normal, postgres does not return an error if you're deleting a row that does not exists, therefore Go does not return an error as well.

Comment: @mkopriva-ok, thanks

Comment: And if you want to determine if a row was deleted or not you can change your query, like so `err := db.QueryRow("DELETE FROM Users WHERE user_id=$1 RETURNING user_id", ID).Scan(&ID)` and if the resulting `err` is equal to `sql.ErrNoRows` then zero rows were deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
func DeleteUser(ID int){
    err = nil
    res, err := DB.Exec("DELETE FROM Users WHERE user_id=$1", ID)

    if err == nil {

       count, err := res.RowsAffected()  
       if err == nil {
          /* check count and return true/false */
       }

    }

    return false

}
```